# How to delete every 2nd column of 2 columns in a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which is something like this

```
       USA x.1 Canada x.2 China x.3 Russia x.4 Germany x.5
data   12  34   34    45    34   67   56    45    45    56
```

I want to delete all the columns with the column name x.1, x.2 and so on. how can i do this in R via subset

Comment: post the output of `dput(df)`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the shortest way to achieve this is:

```
df <- df[c(T,F)]
#     USA Canada China Russia Germany
#data  12     34    34     56      45
```

The vector `c(TRUE,FALSE)` [abbreviated here as `c(T,F)`] is recycled, leading to an alternating series of `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE` etc. Thereby, every second column is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the columns you do want to keep:

```
df <- df[,seq(1,ncol(df),2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex.

```
df[,!grepl("^x\\.[[:digit:]]+$",colnames(df))]
```